# What does "by any stretch of the imagination" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Example sentence would be:

> She was never a great player, not by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Pretty much what it says -- even if you stretch your imagination this is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as anyone could imagine; as much as is imaginable. (Often negative.)